# Parallel payments through a payment gateway? (other than paypal adaptive payments)

Tags: php, xml, soap, payment-gateway

I am building a Travel portal where hotels/flights from multiple vendors are listed (XML Webservices/API) and user can select the same from more than one vendors and checkout the cart (Booking followed by Payments).

Now the vendors do provide Booking API which would be called on each item in the cart. They also provide payment API which accepts credit cards details and process the payment. But for a cart with items from more than one vendor, how can I let the customer pay the total amount in one transaction and then distribute the funds to respective vendors?

The travel portal itself does not charge the customer.

I have looked into PayPal Adaptive payments which probably require the vendor/sellers to have a PayPal accounts but irresepective of that, are there any other options which can solve the issue?

Is there a way to use the vendors' payment API in this scenario? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

it is hard to solve this issue without paypal adaptive but i just give an idea 
you can make your system works like the following:

- customer can add many vendors to his cart
- when the user make checkout => the order is saved in your system and the total money goes to the travel portal bank account
- order stay in pending status (you can show some message to the user about this)
- admin can check each order at the end of every day
- order details page must has links for each vendor, when the admin click it, the money will goes to this vendor
- when all vendors receive their money => order status will be
  success and new email will send to the customer
- if some of vendors has an error in receiving the money, you should has return money button to the customer and make the order as canceled

otherwise you have to do this steps automatically from checkout page (vendor by vendor) to send the money directly to them

also this take too much time to send many requests, so do it by ajax and show some loading photo to the customer

Comment: Thank you for your ideas.. Will see how it goes.